# Celeryd ignores BROKER_URL in /etc/default/celeryd

Tags: python, redis, celery, celeryd

**Summary**

- I am running Celery as a daemon via celeryd ([as per instructions](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html))
- Specified redis as the broker in the configuration file /etc/default/celeryd BROKER_URL="redis://localhost:6379/0"
- Worker log file indicates that BROKER_URL is being ignored as it is still attempting to connect to the default broker.

> ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to
>   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//: Error opening socket: a socket error
>   occurred.

**Question:** Do I need to modify the /etc/init.d/celeryd file beyond the basic template that was provided in the online instructions in order for BROKER_URL to be passed as an argument?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but other properties such as **CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=["json"]** also appear to be getting ignored as the log file continues to warn about W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED

Answer (score 0):

/etc/default/celeryd is configuration for the daemon, and only [these options](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#available-options) will go there. You can configure your celery [instance](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application) with a [settings file or by passing arguments](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#configuration) when creating the instance.